# Single thread with a delay to start

Tags: java, single-threaded

What im trying to do is : Pressing one button change simple value. If value remains unchanged for 3 sec, i wanna execute my method. So i need a single thread which would start(and kill all others) on every button click. I know

```
Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
```

but it can't have a delay. What would be the best practice to do this ?

Comment: do you mean you need a master thread? so it kills all other threads then make new ones right?

Comment: actually no, except the main thread. Sorry didn't mentioned that

Comment: do you have a place that stores all the (removeable) threads? or they are just randomly made

Comment: It is randomly created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you can go with simple `Thread` start-stop/interrupt thing or you can use API's like `ScheduledExecutorService`.
An example of how to do with `ScheduledExecutorService` is below

```
//Start as many threads as you want upon button click... (since you said i want to kill all other threads, so i assume you want to start some threads soon upon button click)
            ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(3);
            service.schedule(new Thread(), 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            service.schedule(new Thread(), 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            service.schedule(new Thread(), 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            //Start single thread after 3 seconds.
            ScheduledExecutorService serviceCheck = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(3);
            serviceCheck.schedule(new Thread(), 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            //In this thread created using "serviceCheck", check with value has not changed then use `service.shutdownNow();` to shutdown all previously started threads and then do whatever you want.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the old `Thread` class or the `Runnable` interface: start the thread as soon as the button is clicked, execute `Thread.sleep(3000)` as first instruction, then check if the value is unchanged.
Before starting the thread check if another thread already exists and, if any, call `interrupt()` on it and handle the `InterruptedException` to gracefully terminate it.

If you want to use the newer concurrent API, note that `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()` returns a  `ScheduledExecutorService` (not a simple `Executor`) and it allows starting a thread with a delay as the name implies.  Check the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).